# How to show that a set of linear mappings form an infinite dimensional dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I am struggling to answer a question for my principles of mathematics class in one of the problem sheets.

The question is as follows

---

Let $V := C[0, 1]$. We shall consider $V$ as a vector space with the usual operations of pointwise addition and pointwise scalar multiplication.

For each $x ∈ [0, 1]$ deﬁne $T_x : C[0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ by, $T_x(f) := f(x)$.

(i) Show that each $T_x ∈ V^∗$

(ii) Show that $\{Tx : x ∈ [0, 1]\}$ is linearly independent and then use this to show that $V^*$ is inﬁnite dimensional.

---

I have sorted out (i) but am struggling to do part 2:

Part (i)

$
\forall f,g \in C[0,1] \\
T_x(f + g) = (f + g)(x) \qquad\text{As the vector space has pointwise addition we can say} \\
T_x(f + g) = (f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) = T_x(f) + T_x(g) \\
\text{We also know: } T_x(\lambda f) = \lambda f(x) = \lambda T_x(f) \text{ due to pointwise scalar multiplication} \\
\Box
$

Part 2 (ii)

????

Answer (score 1):

Part $2$: let $x_1,...,x_n \in [0,1]$ and $s_1,....,s_n \in \mathbb R$ and suppose that

(*) $s_1T_{x_1}+....+s_nT_{x_n}=0$.

We have to show that $s_1=....=s_n=0$.

From (*) we get:

$s_1f(x_1)+...+s_nf(x_n)=0$  for all(!) $f \in V$.

Your turn !

Comment: Nice use of the '(!)' !

Comment: Thanks. "all" is important.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, makes alot of sense, I still dont get how to show the infinite part from this